# Where to store an Rest API

Tags: sql, react-native, api, django-rest-framework

So I wrote an app in React Native. Now I have my Django Rest framework and a mysql database. I know: I should pay a hosting service to host my database and put the React Native code in the playstore. (This is meant symbolically) **But** Now I still have the Django Rest framework project - where should I store that? I may also have profile images in the app. Where should I store those? Sorry if the question seems a bit silly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get a webserver. For example Digital Ocean or Amazon Webservice, etc.. There you have to upload the project and you access the website over your own domain e.g.: [www.yourproject.com](http://www.yourproject.com)

Now you can use your urls for example
[www.yourproject.com/api/user](http://www.yourproject.com/api/user)

I hope I could help you